# Binding 3 textboxes together; same DateTime different format

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, data-binding, textbox

I have three textboxes right now:

```
<TextBox Name="SDate1"  Text="{Binding Source={x:Static System:DateTime.Now}, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy'}"  />
<TextBox Name="SDate2" />
<TextBox Name="STime1" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static System:DateTime.Now}, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='hh:mm:ss'}" />
```

In the code behind:

```
SDate2.Text = String.Format("{0},{1}/{2}",
           now.Year,
           now.DayOfYear.ToString("d3"),
           now.ToString("HHmmss"));
```

What this looks like:

[image]

What I would like to do is, if I edit any part of one textbox, it should edit the others as well at the appropriate part. So If I changed the `2016` part in the first text box to `2017`, the `SDate2` like so:
[image]

This should also work if I change the hours/minutes/seconds in `STime` which will change the last part of `SDate2` and vice versa.

Changing the day in `SDate1` will change the `dayOfYear` in `SDate2` and vice versa.

What would be the best way to achieve something like this?

Edit: I can bind the textboxes together, but the format isn't kept, and it's the same text in all the textboxes.

Edit 2: Here's the code behind in the xaml.cs file I tried.

```
public partial class TestDate : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{      
    private DateTime _dateInViewModel;

    public TestDate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
    public DateTime DateInViewModel
    {

        get { return _dateInViewModel; }
        set
        {
           _dateInViewModel = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DateInViewModel"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the update XAML for the textboxes:

```
<TextBox Name="SDate1" Text="{Binding DateInViewModel, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy'}" />
<TextBox Name="SDate2" Text="{Binding DateInViewModel}" />
<TextBox Name="STime1" Text="{Binding DateInViewModel, StringFormat='hh:mm:ss'}" />
```

Comment: Don't bind the textboxes to `DateTime.Now`, but to each other and make it `TwoWay`. Set the initial value in code behind.

Comment: Do I set the initial value for all three first, or just one and then start the binding? Edit: N/m, right now it copies the first textbox to the others, and they update when each other is changed but the format isn't kept.

Comment: Just set one. If they're bound, others will get the same value.

Comment: That works but, the formatting doesn't work. IE I set `SDate1` in the code behind, and bind the textboxes together, they all show `02/23/2016` instead of their proper formats.

Comment: Been a while since I did anything on wpf, but you can make it work. Either you can set the property/formatting directly on the binding statement, or you need to make a custom converter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because you are binding to separate `DateTime` instances. All three `TextBox`es should bind to the same `DateTime` instance. In a proper MVVM implementation you should have a viewmodel with a `DateTime` property, lets call it `DateInViewModel`:

```
private DateTime _dateInViewModel;
public DateTime DateInViewModel
{
    get { return _dateInViewModel; }
    set
    {
        _dateInViewModel = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DateInViewModel");
    }
}
```

The viewmodel should implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/library/ms229614(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, so the bindings are notified when the property is changing.

Instead of setting `SDate2`'s `Text` to that `string.Format(...)` you just set `DateInViewModel` in the viewmodel:

```
DateInViewModel = DateTime.Now;
```

And finally your XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="SDate1" Text="{Binding DateInViewModel, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy'}" />
<TextBox Name="SDate2" Text="{Binding DateInViewModel}" />
<TextBox Name="STime1" Text="{Binding DateInViewModel, StringFormat='hh:mm:ss'}" />
```

You can change the bindings' `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` to see instant updates as you edit. The default `UpdateSourceTrigger` for the `TextBox`'s `Text` binding is `LostFocus` so other bindings are only notified when you click outside the `TextBox`.

Comment: Thank you! This is how I should be doing it. One question, where would I set the `DateInViewModel` for `SDate2` format?

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work. Keeps saying "NotifyPropertyChanged" doesn't exist in current context. I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Edited my post with the new code. Took out `DateTime.Now`, tried putting it in multiple spots but the `textboxes` were always blank. But that's because of the `PropertyChangedEvent` not working I'm assuming.

Comment: If your `TextBox`es are in this `TestDate` window it should work after setting the window's `DataContext`. Do this after the `InitializeComponent` method call in the constructor: `DateInViewModel = DateTime.Now; DateContext = this;`

Comment: Oh okay it seems to work now! One last question, the string format for SDate2, how do I properly set that with the DateViewModel (since I can't in the xaml)?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good question. You could do it with a converter which implements both the Convert and ConvertBack methods. Convert converting from a DateTime to a string. And the ConvertBack converting the string to the DateTime. Please ask this in a separate question, I'm sure someone or me will find a solution for it. :) Right now I'm on a train getting home ;)