# Custom date format for textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, string-formatting, date-formatting

Related: [Binding 3 textboxes together; same DateTime different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581427/binding-3-textboxes-together-same-datetime-different-format)

I have three `textboxes`, all are supposed to be bound together with the same date. Two of them have normal string formats. The third one has a specific format of `yyyy,jjj/HHmmss`. I can't figure out how to bind this `textbox` to the custom format I have, and make it so if I change any of the date values in it, the other `textboxes` will update and vice versa.

```
private DateTime _dateInViewModel;
public DateTime DateInViewModel
{
    get { return _dateInViewModel; }
    set
    {
        _dateInViewModel = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DateInViewModel");
    }
}

<TextBox Name="SDate1" Text="{Binding DateInViewModel, StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy'}" />
<TextBox Name="SDate2" Text="{Binding DateInViewModel}" />
<TextBox Name="STime1" Text="{Binding DateInViewModel, StringFormat='hh:mm:ss'}" />
```

The custom format can be made like:

```
format = String.Format("{0},{1}/{2}",
                                DateInViewModel.Year,
                                DateInViewModel.DayOfYear.ToString("d3"),
                                DateInViewModel.ToString("HHmmss"));
```

Right now, only `SDate1` and `STime1` bind to each other properly and update when the other is changed.

I made a converter. It properly updates `SDate2` when `SDate1` and `STime1` are changed, but doesn't work when editing `SDate2` to update the others.

```
public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            DateTime test = (DateTime)value;
            string date = String.Format("{0},{1}/{2}",
                                            test.Year,
                                            test.DayOfYear.ToString("d3"),
                                            test.ToString("HHmmss"));
            return (date);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: What you show is an attempt to construct a string from parts, **not** implement a custom format. If you *can* create the format string that returns what you want, you can just put it in the binding

Comment: Wait, so I could just put the `string.format` I have above in the xaml?? I didn't think I could put the methods of `DateTime` like `.Year, .DayOfYear`, etc. in the xaml.

Comment: no, what you are doing with String.Format is actually creating a string from 3 different values. I see that the problem is DateOfYear, which means that you just can't create such a format string. As others answered though, if you want textbox data to be parsed and update the ViewModel, you need the ConvertBack method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the convert back in the converter. This is just an example but you need to parse the value back into original source so other binds can be updated.

since your format is `{0},{1}/{2}` then you need to split it back up and reconstruct the intended date.

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null) return null;
    string strValue = value.ToString();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue) && targetType == typeof(DateTime?))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
    {
        return DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    //year,dayOfYear/Time(HHmmss)
    var parts = strValue.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (parts.Length == 2) {
        var year = parts[0];
        parts = parts[1].Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (parts.Length == 2) {
            var days = parts[0];
            var time = parts[1];

            var date = new DateTime(int.Parse(year), 1, 1)
                            .AddDays(int.Parse(days))
                            .Add(TimeSpan.Parse(time));
            return date;
        }
    }

    DateTime resultDateTime;
    return DateTime.TryParse(strValue, out resultDateTime) ? resultDateTime : value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually had a method in another class that did the converting back. Just pasted it in and it seems to work now. Thank you!